# How to assign an interface variable to the value stored by another

Tags: go, memory-management

**Description of the problem:**

`args[0] = ...` updates `args[0]`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func MyFunc(lambda any) {
    myVars := []any {0}
    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        lambda.(func(...any))(myVars...)
        fmt.Println(myVars[0]) // 0, 2, 4, ..., 60 (good)
    }
}

func main() {
    MyFunc(func(args ...any) {
        args[0] = args[0].(int) + 2
    })
}
```

But when I make variable `v := args[0]` and attempt to update the value of `args[0]` by doing `v = ...`, Go (understandably) reassigns `v` to a new object rather than updating the value of `args[0]`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func MyFunc(lambda any) {
    myVars := []any {0}
    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        lambda.(func(...any))(myVars...)
        fmt.Println(myVars[0]) // 0, 0, 0, ..., 0 (bad)
    }
}

func main() {
    MyFunc(func(args ...any) {
        v := args[0]
        v = v.(int) + 2
    })
}
```

**My question:**

How, using `v`, can I update `args[0]`?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Things I have tried:**

I cannot do `*v = ...`, as this yields compiler error `"invalid operation: cannot indirect v (variable of type any)"`.

I cannot do `v := args[0].(*int); *v = *v + 2;`, as this yields runtime error `"panic: interface conversion: interface {} is int, not *int"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not do the pointer operations correctly. Type-assert the pointer variable `v`. First take the address of the arg value with `&`, then proceed with rest of your logic.

```golang
func main() {
    MyFunc(func(args ...any) {
        v := &args[0]
        *v = (*v).(int) + 2
    })
}
```

[Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/rqm8yOPDEq6)